# Insert Sqlite em tarefa background IntentService

Tags: android, mobile

Estou com um problema com IntentService, eu tenho uma activity com três spinner eles recebem o Estado, Cidade e o Bairro de um Webservice onde o IntentService executa essa tarefa e dentro de onReceive passo para os Spinner. Quando a pessoa seleciona o Estado automaticamente os outros spinner são preenchidos com as cidades e bairros desse estado. Isso funciona corretamente mas preciso que essa ultima consulta do usuário seja salva em um sqlite do android e coloquei o código no mesmo IntentService a questão é que ele consegue inserir no banco sqlite os estados que estão no primeiro spinner só que quando ele vai dar statService() novamente para inserir as cidades o app dá erro e fecha. Só um detalhe se eu tiro o comando abaixo ele funciona corretamente. Eu não sei o porquê desse conflito.

```
ClasseCriarBanco banco = new ClasseCriarBanco(this, "banc.db", null, 1);
                        ContentValues valor = new ContentValues();
                        SQLiteDatabase db = banco.getWritableDatabase();
        //                banco.close();

                        //ClasseCriarBanco banco2 = new ClasseCriarBanco(this, "banc.db", null, 1);
                        SQLiteDatabase dbleitura = banco.getReadableDatabase();
                        String [] colunas = {banco.ID,banco.ESTADO};
        //
                        Cursor cur = db.query(banco.TABELA,colunas,null,null,null,null,null);
                        Cursor cur2 = dbleitura.rawQuery("SELECT _id, estado FROM tabela order by estado desc LIMIT 1",null);

                        if(cur.getCount() > 0){
                            cur.moveToPosition(i-1);
                            registroatual = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(banco.ESTADO));
                            cur2.moveToFirst();
                            ultimoregistro = cur2.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(banco.ESTADO));
                        }else{
                            registroatual = "primeiroregistro";
                            ultimoregistro = "primeiroregistro";
                        }

                        if (pegaurl.equals("http://listarapido.esy.es/estados") && registroatual.equals(ultimoregistro)){
                            valor.put(ClasseCriarBanco.ESTADO, finaljs);
                            db.insert(TABELA,null,valor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gente o problema é que quando vc faz um registro com registerReceiver deve fazer também o unregisterReceiver. Se seu registro for em oncreate deve fechar o registro em onDestroy.